# C# how to control things in different form?

Tags: c#, forms, methods

I'm so confused. In my program I am working on a project of statistical calculator for sport teams.

In my current situation I'm trying to set a team name text in form2 if button 'Win' was pressed and when button 'OK' was pressed in that form2, call the method with switch statement for assigning the value into that form1 label for that team written in form 2.

But I can't understand why my program doesn't change label text from different form. I've seen tutorials, tried to set everything to public and private, use getters and setters but nothing work, and even I know it's supposed to work yet the program is like playing with me and trying to get on my nerves. What the hell am I doing wrong?

```
// declare form1 in form2
StatsForm form1 = new StatsForm();

// call for a method and make a variable (txt_TeamName is in form2)
string teamText = txt_TeamName.Text;
teamCheck(teamText);

// the code with 0 results
public void teamCheck(string teamText) 
{
     switch (teamText)
     {
         case "bluejackets":
             int wins = Convert.ToInt32(form1.lbl_BJackets_Win.Text);
             int winsResult = wins + 1;
             form1.lbl_BJackets_Win.Text = Convert.ToString(winsResult);
             break;
             
             // otherwise, if a team name is incorrect, display this message.
                default:
                    MessageBox.Show("Invalid team name!", "Invalid name.");
                    break;
     }
}
```

Comment: You need to understand the concept of _instances_ and its difference from _class_. Here you are creating a _new_ instance of the StatsForm _class_. This new instance is not the one that you have already shown on your screen and from which you have called the second form. The label that you are updating is on this new instance and this new instance is not shown. You need to pass the first instance to the second form and update that instance.

Comment: Thank you. Don't get how I forgot about this new instance.